# Allow a network folder to be accessed by program but not users

Tags: networking, java, network-shares, shared-folders

Not sure if this belongs here or on stackoverflow, so let me know if it's in the wrong place.

I'm creating a program in which all users will save to a shared folder on the local network using jcifs in java. I don't want the user to be able to view the files in the folder by connecting to smb://192.168.x.x, but I do want the program to be able to access the files (preferably without having to enter a password in the program).

So basically, how can I create an open share that is accessible to jcifs, but not any type of file explorer?

Comment: Well, I'd still be interested to see if this is possible, but assuming it's not, my alternative solution is to run a server that broadcasts the username and password that the client connects to

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but non-standard and thus fragile.

The security model of most OSes are user-based which means permissions are granted to the user and programs running as the user make use of such permissions.

If you want to have permissions finer than the user-level, the standard solution is to have some custom protocol and server-side software to enforce this. For example, have a web service running on the server and authenticate the client connecting. (This would still be subject to spoofing so you'd be better off validating the constraints the client is enforcing rather than checking the client.)

If you really want to hack this and you control all the clients that can access the CIFS share, you can use an application firewall or [HIDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host-based_intrusion_detection_system) which allow you to set fine grained rules on application behaviour. However, this is fragile as the server cannot enforce this.